# How do I add a menu router that works even in the maintenance mode?

Tags: 7, maintenance-mode, routes

when a Drupal site is in maintenance mode (not due to a technical fault), users without permission cannot access any page other than `/user`.

Is there any special hook to define a specific menu router should be allowed in maintenance mode ?

I checked [`user_menu`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_menu/7) but there does not seem to be any clue about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`hook_menu_site_status_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_site_status_alter/7) to change the site status for a specific path.

> Control site status before menu dispatching.
>
> The hook is called after checking whether the site is offline but before the current router item is retrieved and executed by menu_execute_active_handler(). If the site is in offline mode, $menu_site_status is set to MENU_SITE_OFFLINE.

The user module implements that hook ([`user_menu_site_status_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_menu_site_status_alter/7)) to make sure the site is always online for the user, user/login, user/password and user/reset/* paths. It should be simple enough to use the logic from that function to implement it for your custom path, e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_menu_site_status_alter(&$menu_site_status, $path) {
  if ($menu_site_status == MENU_SITE_OFFLINE && $path == 'my-path') {
    $menu_site_status = MENU_SITE_ONLINE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a million times Clive!